VB Macro editor in excel - cross checking data in sheets and keep getting error that specified sheets dont exist
I am trying to cross check data in one excel with two sheets. Every time I try and run my code it gives me the error of "one or both of the specified sheets don exist" even though they are named correctly in my code. I really am stumped, tried to go back and forth with chatgpt but its just giving me the same code with the same error.
What I want the code to do: go to the "materials" column (which is column A) and check the ID #'s match -> if they do then go to the quantity column (column D) and check the numbers match. If the numbers match then mark it green, if the numbers have a difference of 100 or less mark it yellow, and if the numbers have a difference of 100 or more mark it red
Tried to change the name of the sheets, looked online for advice, went back and forth with chatbots and still nothings helped.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
